# Bokeh Hover ToolTip Text Color

Tags: python, bokeh

I am running a bokeh app and in the templates the background color is black and text color is white. This causes my tooltips text color to be white and is not readable on hover.

Code -

```
x = ['CPC', 'AID CHECKS']
counts = [208, 28]
print (x)
print (counts)

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x, counts=counts))

p = figure(x_range=FactorRange(*x), plot_height=600, plot_width=990, title="NPS Locations by Security Checks")

p.xaxis.axis_label_text_font_size = "5pt"
p.xaxis.axis_label_text_font_style='bold'

p.vbar(x='x', top='counts', width=0.9, source=source)

p.add_tools(HoverTool(tooltips=[("LOCATION", "@x"), ("TOTAL", "@counts")]))


p.y_range.start = 0
p.x_range.range_padding = 0.1
p.xaxis.major_label_orientation = 1
p.xgrid.grid_line_color = None

show(p)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y889K.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the right way to change the color of a tooltip in Bokeh python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46508535/what-is-the-right-way-to-change-the-color-of-a-tooltip-in-bokeh-python)

Answer (score 0):

Bokeh tooltip elements have `bk-tooltip` class. You can use it to override the font color with a more specific CSS selector.

```
/* Assuming you have something like this in your template, */
body {
    color: white;
}

/* this should do the trick. */
div.bk-tooltip {
    color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This has been answered before.
[using .html](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46514636/11130088)
Also there is the bokeh documentation on it, which I would highly recommend. At first it will seem a bit overwhelming, though once you get to understand their philosophy, the documentation will be extremely helpful.
[link to the user guide](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/tools.html#custom-tooltip)