# Changing ALL background color from a ToolTip

Tags: python, tooltip, bokeh, background-color

So I read this really insightful [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46508535/what-is-the-right-way-to-change-the-color-of-a-tooltip-in-bokeh-python) on how to change the background color in a tooltip for bokeh.

However, when I actually did this solution, a white 5px "border" still remains

```
hover = HoverTool( tooltips="""
    <div style ="border-style: solid;border-width: 15px; background-color:black;">         
        <div>
            <span style="font-size: 12px; color: white;font-family:century gothic;">@height{0,000}</span>
            <span style="font-size: 12px; color: white;font-family:century gothic;"> Observations</span>
        </div>
    </div>
"""
)
```

Please see the [image]

How do I get rid of this white "border" (I believe it's padding between the tooltip box and the tooltip contents)?
As you can see, I am going for a full "dark" theme, so this white is super jarring.

Answer (score 0):

The styling of the `Tooltip` and the padding is defiend [here](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/branch-3.3/bokehjs/src/less/tooltips.less#L21). The padding can be ajusted.

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_notebook
from bokeh.models import HoverTool
output_notebook()

hover = HoverTool(tooltips="""
    <div>
        <style type="text/css">:host { padding: 0px; }</style>
        <div style ="border-style: solid; border-width: 5px; background-color:black;">
            <span style="font-size: 12px; color: white;">Observations</span>
        </div>
    </div>
"""
)

p = figure(width=300, height=300, x_range=(0,3))
p.circle(x=2.5, y=3)
p.add_tools(hover)
show(p)
```

[image: adapted padding for tooltips]

The solution is based on the idea of overwriting the css with an [`InlineStyleSheet`](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/styling/dom.html#stylesheets) which can be passed to some models.